# What does subfacility method in pandas do?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was editing some code at work and found a line with a pandas data frame method called "subfacility" ("o" is the dataframe):

```
subfacility = np.copy(o.subfacility[o.plot_flag == 1])
```

Does anyone know what this method does?  I looked online and couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: `subfacility` is likely a column of the DataFrame `o`.

Comment: See [attribute access](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#attribute-access)

Comment: btw this statement copies a copy of the subarray, `np.copy` can be replaced with `.values`